# Game engine/framework with web deployment option

Tags: ios, web, unity-game-engine

I know Unity can deploy to web besides iOS, Android and other devices. What are alternatives? Requirements are iOS and web. Android would be nice too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Air ... but it's very slow for complex apps(games). Adobe is working on making it competitive but right now it's not something you can use. I'm a flash developer myself and I choose Corona SDK for porting some of my games to iOS and Android.

If you want all 3 ... web, iOS, Android then Unity is the way to go.